# do_compile is not getting called when an image class is inherited in Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a requirement to inherit an image class( `*.bbclass` )and run a script from image recipe but my `do_compile` is not getting called.

For simplicity, I am putting up minimal sample code from `poky` source here which does similar thing which I want.

I have created a test recipe called `inherit-test_0.1.bb` under my own created layer `meta-raxy`.

Here is the `inherit-test_0.1.bb` recipe file,

```
SUMMARY = "Inherit Test Application"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

inherit image

do_compile () {
    echo MyRecipe
}
```

When I compile this recipe by `bitbake inherit-test` after setting up `oe-init-build-env`, I do not see my `do_compile` gets compiled since there is no log file present in working directory `poky/build/tmp/work/qemux86-poky-linux/inherit-test/0.1-r0/temp/log.do_compile` with the line `MyRecipe`

And if I remove `inherit image`, I see `do_compile` gets compiled as shown below in log file,

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
MyRecipe
DEBUG: Shell function do_compile finished
```

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: To run a command on rootfs creation, you should use [ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND). You can see an example [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#migration-1.6-variable-changes-variable-entry-behavior).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheriting "image" states `do_compile[noexec] = "1"`, among others, (as you can see in the image.bblcass file) which means that the do_compile task won't be executed. That is one of the several ways Yocto offers for delete a task.

Comment: I tried two ways to verify but same behavior(do_compile didn't get compiled): 1. commenting out `do_compile[noexec] = "1"` and 2. Adding `unset do_compile[noexec]`

Comment: Compiling something in image recipe is against Yocto philosophy, and you shouldn't patch anything in upstream layers. (see my other comment below)